# Swift 5 NumberPad extended buttons unresponsive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, numpad

Ive got a done button on a numberpad and when i enter a value and press done the value isnt saved/registered. My code is below:

Im using UIRepresentable protocol (courtesy of Rajeev Kumar S)

```
struct TestTextfield: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var keyType: UIKeyboardType
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
      textfield.keyboardType = keyType
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textfield.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(textfield.doneButtonTapped(button:)))
        toolBar.items = [doneButton]
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
        textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        return textfield
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text

    }
}

extension  UITextField{
    @objc func doneButtonTapped(button:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
       self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

And ive got this in my content view

```
struct ContentView : View {
@State var text = ""

var body: some View {
    TestTextfield(text: $text, keyType: UIKeyboardType.phonePad)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
    )
}
```

[image: This is the numberpad]

This is what i am using:

- Swift 5
- Xcode 11.5

Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your representable class to this!

```
struct TestTextfield: UIViewRepresentable {

        @Binding var text: String

        var keyType: UIKeyboardType

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
            let textfield = UITextField()
          textfield.keyboardType = keyType
            let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textfield.frame.size.width, height: 44))
            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(textfield.doneButtonTapped(button:)))
            toolBar.items = [doneButton]
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
            textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            textfield.delegate = context.coordinator
            return textfield
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {

            uiView.text = text
        }

        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator($text)
        }

        class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

            @Binding var text: String

            init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
                self._text = text
            }

            func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

                text = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? ""

                return true
            }
        }
    }
```

Try it!